# Excel - Entries in List of values be based on some other column value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

We have a scenario in excel (2010) where the list of values present in a dropdown change dynamically based on some column of that row. For eg. Consider the "Supervisor" dropdown in sheet1 below:

```
Emp Grade   Supervisor
A   14  
B   12  
C   13  
D   12  
E   12  
F   13  
G   14
```

Now let's say there is a dropdown for the supervisor. For every employee, the supervisor can be a person of his grade or higher grades only. So, for eg. For grade 13 employee, can have a supervisor with grade 13 or grade 14 only, not grade 12.

How can I write a custom condition like this inside the list of values? I have tried with things like named range, offset etc. but none allows specifying custom conditions. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following document to be helpful in creating dependent Data Validation dropdowns: DV0064 - Dependent Lists Clear Cells, which can be downloaded here (for free):

http://www.contextures.com/excelfiles.html#DataVal

You can tailor the example to your needs.

Comment: Checked that, but that doesn't address my scenario

Answer (score 0):

```
=OFFSET('validation pivot'!$A$1,0,1,COUNTIFS('validation pivot'!$A:$A,">="&B2),1)
```

The supervisor needs to be at least his pay grade (>=B2). In order to have it work you need to have the pivot inserted in *validation pivot* A1. How to create the pivot (hasty notes):

1. add grade and emp 'emp as subset
2. tabular view 'to have separate columns
3. repeat labels ' to be able to count them
4. remove autosums(both within and total) 'to not deal with evading it
5. hide column labels and filters 'same
6. descending order(grade) 'to get a simple match method
7. data: store none 'to refresh the descending order every time

See uploaded [sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-773Ttgo1z6aGhCdVlDME1wM1U/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

This code (column A = EMP, B = Grade, C = Supervisor)

```
Sub test()

Dim actualgrade As Integer
Dim lastRowA As Integer
Dim numbers As String

lastRowA = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Sheets("sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRowA '1 = headers
actualgrade = Cells(i, 2)

For j = 2 To lastRowA
If Cells(j, 2) >= actualgrade Then
numbers = numbers & " " & Cells(j, 1).Value
End If
Next j

Cells(i, 3).Value = numbers
numbers = ""

Next i
End Sub
```

Makes this result:

```
Emp Grade   Supr
A   14   A G
B   12   A B C D R F G
C   13   A C F G
D   12   A B C D R F G
R   12   A B C D R F G
F   13   A C F G
G   14   A G
```

Feel free to change it like you need it

Comment: The values this code gives are correct, but they should appear as list of values in the supervisor dropdown. How do I link this function to the data-validation list of values?

Comment: Just set in the properties of your dropdown the range to `$C$2:$C$8`

Comment: do you mean a standalone dropdown or dropdown in your cell? If you need it in the cell then change the code that it copies the values among each other for each Emp in a temp datasheet and set the range as input by data valudation of each cell

Comment: If I understood you right, the following needs to be done:
a) Modify your code so that it copies the above results in "Sheet2" - one column per supervisor
b) Apply drop down to the field Supervisor (Column C) in "Sheet1" so that the source of this list points to the data in sheet2. Eg. C2 points to Sheet2!A:A, C3 points to Sheet2!B:B, etc

If this understanding is correct, there is an issue here. The number of employees will continue to increase, so how to add this drop down for every new employee? A macro?